# What can happen in two concurrent NetworkStream.BeginWrite calls?

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, concurrency, tcp

I have two methods on my `Sender` class:

```
public void SendMessage(OutgoingMessage msg)
{
    try
    {
        stream.BeginWrite(msg.TcpData, 0, 16, messageSentCallback, msg);
    }
    catch
    {
        // ...
    }
}

private void messageSentCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    stream.EndWrite(result);

    if (result.IsCompleted)
        onDataSent(result.AsyncState as OutgoingMessage);
}
```

Other parts of the program can call (if they have an access to the Sender) the `SendMessage()` method. Since the program works in multi-threading environment, multiple threads have access to the Sender object.

I have **2 questions:**

**Q1)** Would making two concurrent calls to the `SendMessage` method be able to mess up the TCP communication (by filling the TCP outgoing buffer with mixed data)?

**Q2)** Would enclosing the `stream.BeginWrite()` call into the `lock { }` solve this problem?

As far as I understand, the call to BeginWrite simply stores the data into the TCP outgoing buffer. Is that right?

Comment: This can't go wrong, the second call throws an exception.  Locking the BeginWrite call is no fix, it takes but a few microseconds.  You'd need to fix the logical bug in your code.

Comment: Do you suppose that the required scenario would be to not allow another BeginWrite until the stream.EndWrite has been called? Would that work? Yeah, the lock would block other threads from calling the BeginWrite, but that doesn't mean that the socket (or its buffer) is in a state that can write again (until the EndWrite is called). Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a lock is required to avoid problems. However, I would switch to a different approach, both to solve concurrency problems as well as to make the thread interaction more easy to reason about.

You could have a shared queue where several threads put requests that need to be written to the stream. A single thread then reads requests from the queue and makes write operations. Now it's much easier to understand what is going on and you don't have to worry about synchronizing the writes. You could use one of the concurrent collections like `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this approach, however, in that case, additional thread management is required - when to start it, how often to send to TCP and what to do in the case of an error. But it's definitely better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Says

> As long as there is one unique thread for the write operations and one
>   unique thread for the read operations, there will be no
>   cross-interference between read and write threads and no
>   synchronization is required.

Which means that if you have more than one threads sending data then you should use `lock` to make sure only one thread calls `BeginWrite` at a time in order to send data without any interference

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to minimize blocking and maintain high concurrency with multiple writer threads I would recommend using the [`Socket.SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync.aspx) which accepts a [`SocketAsyncEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx).

You could preallocate a number of SocketAsyncEventArgs (with its associated buffer space) that are used as writers, in which case, rather than having a lock you would have a [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) which would allow a number of 'simultaneous' writes pushing the synching lower down the protocol stack.

- [Here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nclsamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=socket%20performance) is a Code Gallery sample that could get you started (also demonstrates pooling for your buffers.)
- [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod) is a codeproject article that also demonstrates its use.

Good luck!